# How to get updated or new records by comparing two dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes like this:

```
df2.show()

+----+-------+------+
|NAME|BALANCE|SALARY|
+----+-------+------+
|PPan|     11|   500|
|Liza|     20|   900|
+----+-------+------+

df3.show()

+----+-------+------+
|NAME|BALANCE|SALARY|
+----+-------+------+
|PPan|     10|   700|
| Cal|     70|   888|
+----+-------+------+
```

`df2` here, represents existing database records and `df3` represents new records/updated records(any column) which need to be inserted/updated into db.For ex: `NAME=PPan` the new balance is `10` as per `df3`. so For `NAME=PPan` entire row has to be replaced in `df2` and for `NAME=Cal`, a new row has to be added and for `name=Liza` will be untouched like this:

```
    +----+-------+------+
    |NAME|BALANCE|SALARY|
    +----+-------+------+
    |PPan|     10|   700|
    |Liza|     20|   900|
    | Cal|     70|   888|
    +----+-------+------+
```

How can I achieve this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to join both dataframes using `full` method to keep unmatched rows (new) and to updating the matched records I do prefer to use `select` with `coalesce` function:

```py
joined_df = df2.alias('rec').join(df3.alias('upd'), on='NAME', how='full')
# +----+-------+------+-------+------+
# |NAME|BALANCE|SALARY|BALANCE|SALARY|
# +----+-------+------+-------+------+
# |Cal |null   |null  |70     |888   |
# |Liza|20     |900   |null   |null  |
# |PPan|11     |500   |10     |700   |
# +----+-------+------+-------+------+

output_df = joined_df.selectExpr(
  'NAME', 
  'COALESCE(upd.BALANCE, rec.BALANCE) BALANCE', 
  'COALESCE(upd.SALARY, rec.SALARY) SALARY'
)

output_df.sort('BALANCE').show(truncate=False)
+----+-------+------+
|NAME|BALANCE|SALARY|
+----+-------+------+
|PPan|10     |700   |
|Liza|20     |900   |
|Cal |70     |888   |
+----+-------+------+
```